# How to get a column in table

Tags: php, zend-framework2

In zend 2, I've tried to get a column in my db through library "Sql" using adapter.
This is my code:

```
$adapter = new Adapter(array(
        'driver' => 'Pdo',
        'hostname' => 'localhost',
        'database' => 'myDB',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
    ));
    $sql = new Sql($adapter);
    $select = $sql->select();
    $select->from('sanpham');
    $select->columns(array('maHang'));

    echo $select->getSqlString().'<br/>';

    $selectString = $sql->getSqlStringForSqlObject($select);
    $results = $adapter->query($selectString, $adapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE);
    Debug::dump($select);
```

But Zend cant execute it and return an error like this:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\View\Exception\RuntimeException'
>   with message 'Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render
>   template "error"; resolver could not resolve to a file' in ...
>   ...\library\Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer.php on line 499

And now I stuck in this step in my project, I don't know how to solve this error.
Can u give me a solution to get over this or suggest me an other way to get a column in my db?
Thanks,

Comment: There is no view named error (in view/controler/error os similar)

Comment: All DB-Query stuff should go into a `try/catch`-statement anyways. And then you can use hyper professional `die()` debugging to see what's wrong with the query. The error, as has been mentioned above, is very verbose and easily fixable. just add an error template.